# How to get PersonaID to make a valid call to GetPersona operation on EWS

Tags: javascript, outlook, exchangewebservices

Id like to make a call to the EWS Getpersona-operation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getpersona-operation) but im unsure how I get the PersonaID that needs to be passed in?

Im assuming this is the ID of the person id like to retrieve the information about and in my instance I want this to the the logged in user.

Can anybody point me to where I might get this?

So to continue on the advice given I have been trying to make a call using the 'GetUserSetting' operation.

```
function sendRequest() {

console.log('get user');
mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(getRequest(), callback); 

}


function getRequest() {

var result =
'<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>' +
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover"' +
    ' xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"' +
    ' xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
    ' xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
    '<soap:Header>' +
    '<a:RequestedServerVersion>Exchange2007_SP1</a:RequestedServerVersion>' +
    '<wsa:Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover/Autodiscover/GetUserSettings</wsa:Action>' +
    '<wsa:To>https://pod51042.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.svc</wsa:To>' +
    '</soap:Header>' +
    '<soap:Body>' +
    '<a:GetUserSettingsRequestMessage xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover">' +
    '<a:Request>' +
    '<a:Users>' +
    '<a:User>' +
    '<a:Mailbox>emailhere</a:Mailbox>' +
    '</a:User>' +
    '</a:Users>' +
    '<a:RequestedSettings>' +
    '<a:Setting>PublicFolderInformation</a:Setting>' +
    '</a:RequestedSettings>' +
    '</a:Request>' +
    '</a:GetUserSettingsRequestMessage>' +
    '</soap:Body>' +
    '</soap:Envelope>'; 

return result; 
}


function callback(asyncResult) {


var result = asyncResult.value;
var context = asyncResult.context;

console.log('result :' + result);
console.log('context :' + context);
console.log('asyncResult :' + asyncResult);
debugger; 
}
```

The result of both result and context are undefined and inspecting the asyncResult within the debugger gives simply 'The Request is Invalid'

[image]
many thanks

Comment: The only operation that returns the persona id is the FindPeople operation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/findpeople-operation

Comment: Thank you for that.  I have tried to make some test calls (based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/findpeople-operation) and it doesnt seem to be returning any values. When I check the asyncResult.value it is showing as 'Undefined'

Comment: You need to show a bit more detail of the code your using its probably a error in the request but it hard to say without seeing the request. The EWSEditor has a sample in the samples directory you could try running if you want something outside of you code to test

Comment: @GlenScales I have updated above to show code being used and outcome of debugging

Comment: So first thing is your RequestedServerVersion is wrong FindPeople only appeared in Exchange2013 and what you posted has nothing to do with FindPeople or personas it appears you trying to get the PublicFolderInformation?